# How to create temporary select field?

Tags: 8, forms

I added a field:

```
$form['field_brand_selector']['#type'] = "select";
$form['field_brand_selector']['#title'] = "Brand";
$form['field_brand_selector']['#required'] = false;
```

This field is populated dynamically using Javascript. However, if I try to save the form, I get:

```
Illegal choice 49124 in Brand element.
```

I suspect that this is because I don't have this:

```
$form['field_brand_selector']['#options'] = $options;
```

So Drupal doesn't know which values are allowed for this Dropdown Selector. But seeing as this dropdown selector is not actually a field that must be saved, is there a way to "ignore" it's submission when I press save, so that I don't get the illegal Brand element error?

Comment: "This field is populated dynamically using Javascript" - not possible. Drupal has to have all values available. You could use hidden instead.

Comment: If you don't need the select box to actually be apart of the Drupal form and you are already altering the select with javascript you could you insert the whole select item via javascript. That should stop Drupal trying to validate it.

Or if not you could probably use the form API's ajax functionality to populate the options. That is the Drupal way to have dynamic selects.

Answer (score -1):

Probably a hack, but this is how I solved it:

```
$form['field_brand_selector'] = array(
    '#type' => 'inline_template',
    '#template' => '{{ somecontent | raw }}',
    '#context' => [ 'somecontent' => 
    '
        <label for="edit-field-brand-selector">Brand</label>
        <select class="" id="edit-field-brand-selector" name="field_brand_selector" readonly="readonly"></select>
    '],
    '#weight' => 8,
);
```

This way Drupal doesn't validate the field I added.